# Analyzing the feedback network of an LM2576/LM2596 regulator on this battery charger circuit

Tags: dc-dc-converter, buck, feedback

[image: 3A Battery Charger]

I'm trying to figure out how this [3A Battery Charger with Logic-Level Current Controls](https://www.ti.com/lit/an/snoa327b/snoa327b.pdf) from Texas Instrument works.

I know how output voltage feedback, current sampling, and op-amp section work.  The problem is that I cannot understand how Q1 and Q2 could help to increase the current flow (I can't analyze the new current paths and the effects of increasing output current driven by Q1 and Q2 on the feedback pin of LM2576.)

Based on the description from the document:

> Turning Q1 on (by putting a “1” on logic input “A”) provides an increase of 4:1 in load current. The load current is higher with Q1 on because R2 and R3 divide down the output of U2 by 4:1, requiring U2 to
> output a higher voltage to get the 1.23V on the feedback line of U1. Higher voltage at the output of U2 means that more charging current is flowing through R8 (also the battery).
> The operation of Q2 is similar to Q1: when Q2 is turned on by putting a logic “1” on input “B”, the load current is increased by a factor of 10:1. This is because when Q2 is on, the sense voltage coming from R8 is divided down by R10 and R11, requiring ten times as much signal voltage across R8 to get the same voltage at the non-inverting input of U2.

How do I analyze it?

Also, the document declares:

> Although both attenuating dividers could have been placed on the input side of U2, putting the 4:1 divider at the output improves the accuracy and noise immunity of the amplifier U2 (because the voltage applied to the input of U2 is larger, this reduces the input-offset voltage error and switching noise degradation.)

How does moving Q1 from input to the output of the op-amp improve the accuracy and noise immunity of the amplifier U2?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For example, if Q2 is turned ON and Q1 turned OFF. We have an additional voltage divider at the input of U2 (non-inverting amplifier). The R11 is connected between 0V and U2 non-inverting input. Thus, the U2 gain drops. So we need a more current via R8 to get 1.23V at the FB pin. The gain is now equal to:

\$\large A_V  = (1 + \frac{R_4}{R_7}) \times \frac{R_{11}}{R_{10} + R_{11}} \approx 333 \times 0.1  \approx 33 [V/V]\$

Therefore the R8 current (charging current) will be equal to:

\$\large I_{R8} = \frac{\frac{1.23V}{33}}{R_8} = 0.745A\$

We have a similar situation when Q1 is turned ON. But this time we have a voltage divider at the U2 output. Which also reduces U2 voltage gin. So, that more current can flow through R8.

If the FB pin voltage is less than 1.23V the U1 will increase the output voltage. And if is FB pin voltage is higher than 1.23V U1 will decrease the output voltage.

Answer (score 3):

The current feedback goes thru the non-inverting input "system return" while the ground reference is on the inverting side."Return=0V"

By attenuating A at the output a divider ratio of 4 forces the current to be 4x as great to match the reference. (10k/10k+30.1k = 1/4) This is also the side with a HF-reject RC noise feedback, so A does not amplify that noise.

Similarly attenuating the B input 113/1113 or 1/10 also forces the current to reach 10x the normal levels with A+B off for the fastest boost when B is ON.